# How to resolve CORS in Blazor webassembly when fetching data from an external API

Tags: cors, blazor-webassembly

When trying to fetch data from an external API in **Blazor Web Assembly** I get the following error, while the same request works fine from any browser, Postman and from Blazor Server Application:

Access to fetch at 'https://boi.org.il/PublicApi/GetExchangeRates' from origin 'https://localhost:7246' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

The same error occurs in the following situation:

- stand alone Web Assemply project
- hosted web assembly project with or without adding CORS policy to the Blazor Server side
- copying and adding all Postman parameters to the request
- using the build in http in the Blazor project
- using RestSharp Nuget
- running the stand alone Web Assemply project in IIS with SSL

To reproduce the error you can simply paste the following public api URL in your browser and see that it works just fine but won't work from stand alone web assembly.
https://boi.org.il/PublicApi/GetExchangeRates

I read a lot about this problem but they all address the solution to the server side, but in this case it won't make sense it is server side related.
There are few more open API that I tried and they all act the same.

What am I missing?
I need to access an external API directly from the client side.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The API server (https://boi.org.il/PublicApi/GetExchangeRates) needs to have the CORS headers that will allow your Blazor app to access it. If you do not control that server then you will need to have your own server access the API and act as a relay for your Blazor app and the API.

> I read a lot about this problem but they all address the solution to the server side

That is because this is not a client side fixable problem.